# ifstream of <fstream> won't compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ifstream

I `#include` these headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

but however this piece of code:

```
ifstream inFile;
```

still wont compile. what could be the problem? Im using Visual Studio 2010, Win32 C++.

Comment: **General advice:** we want to see a testcase to know what you did wrong; the error message wouldn't hurt either. Answers below will be guesses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a `using namespace std;` at the top of your code so you don't have to fully qualify standard C++ stuff, but it's considered bad form by a large number of developers.

I simply prefix the standard stuff with `std::`, which makes the code longer:

```
std::cout << "Hello, world.\n";
```

but keeps me out of trouble vis-a-vis namespace clashes.

The following transcript shows the use of `std::` prefixes in action:

```
$ cat testprog.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>

    int main (void) {
        int n;
        std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
        inFile >> n;
        std::cout << "File contained " << n << '\n';
        return 0;
    }

$ cat input.txt
42

$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -o testprog testprog.cpp ; ./testprog
File contained 42
```

Answer (score 3):

The type is `std::ifstream`. You must write it out in full, unless you brought the qualified name into scope by another means.